# Laravel 5.6 - Increment multiple same row columns in single statement?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

Using eloquent model `User`, how can we increment 2 columns on the same row by 1 (in a single statement)?

This single statement works but only for incrementing a single column:

```
User::where('id',$userId)->increment('column1');
```

These following two attempts did not work:

```
User::where('id',$userId)->increment('column1')->increment('column2');

User::where('id',$userId)->increment(['column1','column2']);
```

Any ideas how to solve this in a single statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use raw query and update. Eg.:

```
    User::where('id',$userId)->update([
        'column1' => DB::raw('column1 + 1'),
        'column2' => DB::raw('column2 + 1'),
    ]);
```